# Al subir mi página al host las fuentes no se aplican

Tags: html5, hosting, localhost, fuentes, host

He desarrollado un sitio web y al visualizarlo de forma local las fuentes sí se aplican, pero al subir este con todo y las fuentes en los mismos directorios en el host no se aplican. La p´´agina la he subido a Hostgator ¿Qué debo hacer?

En el archivo index mando llamar las fuentes desde fonts.css, el directorio está bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en seguida se ve como se manda llamar la fuente desde fonts.css

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0");
   src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon la parte donde llamas a las fuentes. Además indica dónde estás subiendo tu web; apache, iis, etc

Comment: ¿No has pensado en utilizar Azure, crear una máquina virtual y montar un servidor en nginx? Apostaría por cualquier otro servicio como Digital Ocean, Blue Host o un servidor propio, no res recomendable utilizar hostings, debido a que limitan mucho al usuario

Comment: Hola Osvaldo, podrías mostrarnos el arbol de directorios, me extraña un poco el **"../fonts, etc"**, parece estar indicando que las fuentes están en una carpeta "superior" al html, es así?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si las fuentes se muestran correctamente cuando se visualizan de forma local pero no cuando se cargan en el servidor, es posible que haya un problema con las rutas de las fuentes en el código HTML o CSS.

Aquí hay algunas cosas que puedes hacer para solucionar el problema:

Verifica que las rutas de las fuentes son correctas: asegúrate de que las rutas de las fuentes en el código HTML o CSS sean correctas y apunten a la ubicación correcta en el servidor.

Verifica que las fuentes se han cargado en el servidor: asegúrate de que las fuentes se han cargado correctamente en el servidor y se encuentran en la ubicación correcta. Puedes hacer esto mediante la conexión FTP al servidor y verificar que los archivos de fuentes se encuentren en la ruta especificada en el código HTML o CSS.

Verifica que las fuentes están accesibles: Asegúrate de que los archivos de fuentes se encuentran en un directorio al que se pueda acceder públicamente. A veces los servidores bloquean el acceso a los archivos de fuentes para proteger los datos, por lo que puede que necesites ajustar los permisos del directorio para permitir el acceso.

Verifica que las fuentes están en el formato adecuado: Verifica que las fuentes están en un formato que es compatible con los navegadores web. Los formatos de fuente más comunes son .ttf, .woff, .woff2, y .eot.

Espero que estos consejos te ayuden a solucionar el problema con las fuentes en tu sitio web alojado en Hostgator. Si el problema persiste, contacta con su soporte técnico para obtener ayuda adicional.

Comment: Suena a ChatGPT esta respuesta, quizá estoy equivocado.

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que todo estaba bien, el error fue un problema de compatibilidad del host con fuentes distintas a woff o woff2. Se solucionó únicamente llamando la fuente en formato woff.